# VC0706 card failed, or not present

Tags: sd-card

I'm trying to follow this tutorial here:

https://learn.adafruit.com/ttl-serial-camera/using-the-camera

Here's what my serial log is printing-- I've added a few commands for logging:

```
Arduino version is: 10605
Chip Select is: 4
VC0706 Camera snapshot test
Card failed, or not present
```

I know my SD card works because when I use this program: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadWrite

it works just fine. What am I messing up?

I'm using an arduino uno with wifi shield.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Comparing and contrasting with the SD card file -- I've found that if you comment out the following -- it works. Maybe this will help someone.

```
//#if !defined(SOFTWARE_SPI)
//#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
//  if(chipSelect != 53) pinMode(53, OUTPUT); // SS on Mega
//#else
//  if(chipSelect != 10) pinMode(10, OUTPUT); // SS on Uno, etc.
//#endif
//#endif
```